# Problemas con la clase `Scanner`

Tags: java, eclipse, scanner

Estuve descargando **Java** y **Eclipse** a mi nueva máquina para trabajar mis programas. Durante la ejecución me ha devuelto error en la clase `Scanner`.

Escribí un código básico de prueba y me sigue devolviendo el error. No sé si es porque el lenguaje no es compatible o algo estoy omitiendo, aunque mi prueba del famoso "HOLA MUNDO" se compiló sin problemas.

Mi código de prueba es:

```java
package prueba;
import java.util.*;
public class prueba2 {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner entrada = new Scanner("System.in");
        int num;
        System.out.println("INGRESE NUM");
        num = entrada.nextInt();
        System.out.println("EL NUM ES "+ num);
    }
}
```

Y el error es:

```sh
INGRESE NUM
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
at java.base/java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:939)
at java.base/java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1594)
at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2258)
at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2212)
at prueba.prueba2.main(prueba2.java:10)
```

¿Alguien me podría ayudar?

Answer (score 5):

Tienes un error en el constructor de `Scanner`

```java
public class prueba2 {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner entrada=new Scanner("System.in"); //aquí
        int num;
        System.out.println("INGRESE NUM");
        num=entrada.nextInt();
        System.out.println("EL NUM ES "+ num);
    }
}
```

Ya que para tomar algún dato por la consola, se debe de pasar como parámetro al constructor `System.in` a secas, sin comillas dobles:

```
    Scanner entrada=new Scanner(System.in); //sin comillas
    int num;
    System.out.println("INGRESE NUM");
    num= entrada.nextInt();
    System.out.println("EL NUM ES "+ num);
```

El error es producido ya que al pasar con comillas dobles, lo toma como un `String` a leer, como lo especifica en su [información oficial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html)(*en inglés*) cuando pasas un `String` como parámetro al constructor, este construye un nuevo escáner que produce valores escaneados a partir de la cadena especificada, y esto lo estas tratando de pasar a una variable de tipo `int`. Lo cual no es posible, al ser diferentes tipos de datos.

Answer (score 0):

Para crear una instancia de la clase Scanner:

```
  Scanner entrada=new Scanner(System.in);
```

Observa que no es un String el que recibe como parámetro sino un `InputStream`

Answer (score 0):

Para crear un objeto de clase `Scanner`, normalmente pasamos el objeto predefinido `System.in`, que representa el flujo de entrada estándar.

Podemos pasar un objeto de clase `File` si queremos leer la entrada de un archivo. 
Al tenerlo con comillas no lo coge como objeto, lo está cogiendo como `String` entonces de ahí el error el está esperando un Objeto.

```
//Importas la clase.
import java.util.Scanner;

Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
```